# Generate distributions in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am using the following code to generate exponential distribution between [0,1] and normal distribution between [0,1]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "boost/random.hpp"
#include "boost/generator_iterator.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   typedef boost::mt19937 RNGType;
   RNGType rng;

   //for generating exponential distribution
   boost::exponential_distribution<0,1> one_to_six;
   boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::exponential_distribution<> >
                dice(rng, one_to_six);
   double number = dice();                    
   cout<<"random number according to exponential distribution="<<number<<"\n";

   //for generating normal distribution
   boost::normal_distribution<0,1> one_to_six1;
   boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::normal_distribution<> >
                dice1(rng, one_to_six1);
   double number1 = dice1();                    
   cout<<"random number according to normal distribution="<<number<<"\n";
}
```

But I dont know why I am getting error with the code. Can someone please help me figure out as to where am I going wrong. I am using c++11.

The error which I am getting is:

```
 no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘boost::normal_distribution<>’
```

As suggested by Barry I tried to change the code to:

```
int main()
{
   typedef boost::mt19937 RNGType;
   RNGType rng;

   //for generating exponential distribution
   boost::exponential_distribution<double> one_to_six;;
   boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::exponential_distribution<> >
                dice(rng, one_to_six);
   double number = dice();                    
   cout<<"random number according to exponential distribution="<<number<<"\n";

   //for generating normal distribution
   boost::normal_distribution<double> one_to_six1;
   boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::normal_distribution<> >
                dice1(rng, one_to_six1);
   double number1 = dice1();                    
   cout<<"random number according to normal distribution="<<number<<"\n";
}
```

But I am still getting the error:note: boost::variate_generator::variate_generator(Engine, Distribution)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @JimLewis I have posted the error.

Comment: You define `one_to_six` twice as different types. This is illegal. Please post actual code?

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks for pointing out...that was a typo...sorry for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always post and read the compiler errors. In this case, it's very clear:

```
main.cpp:13:36: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
   boost::exponential_distribution<0,1> one_to_six;
                                   ^
/usr/local/include/boost/random/exponential_distribution.hpp:37:16: note: template parameter is declared here
template<class RealType = double>
               ^
main.cpp:20:31: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
   boost::normal_distribution<0,1> one_to_six;
                              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp:256:16: note: template parameter is declared here
template<class RealType = double>
               ^
2 errors generated.
```

[`boost::exponential_distribution`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/exp_dist.html) is defined as:

```
template <class RealType = double,
          class Policy   = policies::policy<> >
class exponential_distribution;
```

So you probably need:

```
boost::exponential_distribution<double> one_to_six;
```

And the same for your [`normal_distribution`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/normal_dist.html) variable. Which, additionally, should take a different name, because currently you have two variables named `one_to_six` in the same scope.

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested but I am still getting the error as specified in the edit in my question

Comment: @JannatArora Compiles for me. What version of boost?

Comment: Thanks a lot...compiles for me too but I am not able to get exponential distribution between [0,1] ..the number which it generates is 1.45

Comment: @JannatArora If it compiles for you, why are you saying you are still getting a compile error?

Comment: Sorry I modified my question..I was making a silly mistake earlier..now it compiles well for me...thanks to you...but I am not able to get exponential distribution between [0,1] ..the number which it generates is 1.45

Comment: @JannatArora If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't change this question to ask something else entirely.

Comment: Ok..sorry .. I'll post this as another question :)